# React functions: changing state after useState

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have a functional component that manages a question that can come from two sources.

A props value comes in indicating the source.

When the source changes, I want to create a new question model object with the new source.

Since I'm doing something like this:

```
const [questionModel, setQuestionModel ] = useState(new QuestionModel(questionSource));
```

For some reasons it thinks, "Oh, I've already got one of those questionModel's. I don't need to make a new one".

So all the old stuff stays there.

If I try to do something like:

```
setQuestionModel(new QuestionModel(questionSource));
```

Then it complains about:

> Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of
> renders to prevent an infinite loop.

I get that infinite loops are bad, but I'm not sure how to make this work in ReactJS functions with hooks.

Back when I was using classes, I could specify something once in the constructor and then adjust it again in the render(). But now that the render is mixed in with the other code for the function, how do I re-render it with the new source?

Is there a force re-render when the props change? I thought it would do that if a prop changed ... but it doesn't.

Comment: If you want a new instance on each render then it doesn't need to be stateful: `const questionModel = new QuestionModel(questionSource);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your props changes but I saw sometimes, that the following misunderstanding creates sometimes problems, where the developer thinks "I changed the object, so why my component doesn't rerender?":

When you create a new object like:

```
const user = { name: "john" };
```

You created an object that, has a property that points to the value "john" like this:

user -> { } -- name --> "john"

user points on an object and when you make name, point to a different value by:

```
user.name = "bob"
```

than user still points to the same object and to react it's the same object
but when you do

```
user = { ...user, name: "bob" };
```

then you would assign a new object and now it's a different object.

Comment: A good reminder. I have made that mistake before. Especially when I'm in JavaScript for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using `useEffect` with a dependency of the prop that is being passed in. Within the effect, set the new question type in local state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Like this...

```js
interface Props {
 source: QuestionSource
}

export function QuestionsModal(props: Props) {
const [questionModel, setQuestionModel] = useState<QuestionModel>(new QuestionModel(questionSource))
useEffect(() => {
    setQuestionModel(new QuestionModel(questionSource))
  }, props.source)
}
```